# Iteration each elements of a list to split it based on a condition - Python

Tags: python, list, split, iteration

I have this list :

```py
names = ['pipeline-1__YearBuilt',
    'pipeline-1__NumberofBuildings',
    'pipeline-1__NumberofFloors',
    'pipeline-1__PropertyGFATotal',
    'onehotencoder__x0_Low-Rise Multifamily',
    'onehotencoder__x0_Medical Office',
    'onehotencoder__x0_Mixed Use Property',
    'onehotencoder__x0_Office',
    'onehotencoder__x0_Other',
    'onehotencoder__x0_Refrigerated Warehouse',
    'onehotencoder__x5_Yes'
]
```

I would like to iterate through each elemens of my list to change it (to clean it for a better readability).

I guess I am close but it doesn't work when I try this :

```py
for n in names:
    new = []
    if n.startswith('pipeline-1'):
        n = n.split('__', 1)[-1]
    else:
        n = n.split('__x', 1)[-1]
    new.append(n)
```

I only get :

```py
new = ['5_Yes']
```

I want to keep only the last part of my string.

If anyone can help please. Thanks

Comment: put `new=[]` outside ur loop

Comment: dont intialise `new = []` in `for` loop

Comment: How many times should `new=[]` happen when you run the code? How many times will it happen, the way you have written it? How can you fix that?

Comment: Not really a complete answer, but your method won't work unless you initialize your list _outside_ the for loop. Just place your "new" (I'd also suggest another name, but that's not an issue per se) as your first line and you won't reset your list with each element

Comment: It was the solution. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will help you:

```
new = []
for n in names:
    if n.startswith('pipeline-1'):
        n = n.split('__', 1)[-1]
    else:
        n = n.split('__x', 1)[-1]
    new.append(n)
```

Your array `new` was overwritten on each loop therefore you see only the last element. Just put it in front of the loop.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Indeed it was the mistake and it works now!

Answer (score 2):

[wrong code]

```py
for n in names:
    new = []
    if n.startswith('pipeline-1'):
        n = n.split('__', 1)[-1]
    else:
        n = n.split('__x', 1)[-1]
    new.append(n)
```

in this way you create a new list called `new` n times, where n is the names length.

You must do something like this:

```
new = []
for n in names:

    if n.startswith('pipeline-1'):
        n = n.split('__', 1)[-1]
    else:
        n = n.split('__x', 1)[-1]
    new.append(n)
```

Comment: Thanks for your time it's perfect!

Answer (score 1):

```
new = []
for n in names:
    if n.startswith('pipeline-1'):
        n = n.split('__', 1)[-1]
    else:
        n = n.split('__x', 1)[-1]
    new.append(n)
```

If `new` is inside your loop each iteration of the loop will reset `new` to `[]`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are starting an empty array for every object in your names array, you should have `new = []` outside the for loop